# Custom color of part of text in Jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, cell

What i need is simple. I have a column in a jtable, and i need to insert a string with different parts colorized. For example:

I need this [string] inserted into a jTable cell.

In the example, only the word "string" should have the red color, everything else gray.

How do i do that?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: i don't have code yet so i have nothing to post

Comment: then there are three way 1. read Oracle tutorial part about Renderer, 2. search here in questions tagged by java + swing + jtable + renderer (tablecellrenderer) 3. waiting for miracle

Comment: and not clear what is part of text is about 1) my`Part` 2) or part of cells can be different somhow

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is by getting the reference to the JLabel for that table cell and changing its foreground to the color you want. How ever this will change the whole cell not a part.

```
JLabel label = (JLabel) testTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
```

For partial coloring you might need two labels, change there forground as per the need and embed them into a new level/container and render the new label/container.

Comment: @mKorbel that will be best. I missed that one.

Comment: One should never maintain components within a model, that's what renderers are for...

Answer (score 0):

mKorbel gave you the answer for example:

```
I need this <html><font color=\"red\">[string]</font></html> inserted into a jTable cell.
```

This should do what you need.

Comment: Sounds good, but how do i add the jLabel into my table. Currently what i have is `model.addRow(new Object []{new JLabel("I need this <html><font color=\"red\">[string]</font></html> inserted into a jTable cell")});`

Comment: @JavaGuy Do not add components to the table model...the table model is suppose to model "data", not view information.  This is what table cell renderers are for...